# Присвоить класс объекту при выборе значения в select

Tags: php, jquery

Задача состоит в том, чтобы присвоить класс ячейке расписания, при редактировании которой, в select'е задается статус: в наборе, открыта, закрыта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то тебе нужно что-то на подобии вот этого:

html

```
<select id="control-select">
    <option value="class1" selected=true>Присвоить класс 1</option>
    <option value="class2">Присвоить класс 2</option>
    <option value="class3">Присвоить класс 3</option>
</select>
<div id="element" class="class1" oldClass="class1">Элемент чего либо</div>
```

css

```
.class1{
    color: red;
}
.class2{
    color: green;
}
.class3{
    color: yellow;
}
```

js(jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#control-select").change(function(){
        className = $(this).val();
        oldClassName = $("#element").attr("oldClass");
        $("#element").attr("oldClass",className);
        $("#element").removeClass(oldClassName).addClass(className);
    });
});
```

[И ссылка где можно потыкать, посмотреть, поправить](http://jsfiddle.net/4zmw8nx7/)